# what is the best solution for connect to users local database, from server?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, cloud, database-connection, connection-string

We have an application on cloud which can connect to users local databases(on their systems). so the database and the application are not on same server machine and because of this, some times we'v getting:

> The underlying provider  failed on open

what's your solution to resolve this problem or at least; Reducing the likelihood of error in this case ?

for more information: our used technologies are `EntityFramework`  and `MVC5` web application.

[image]

Comment: Let me get this straight, you have a web application in the cloud, and you want the application to connect to a database stored on the local drive?

Comment: @Neil yes! exactly

Comment: Web applications are not the same as applications on a local network.   The web browser doesn't (normally) have access to local files, and the web server doesn't have direct access to any files on the local drive (normally).

Comment: @Neil yes.. but we will solve it ...the only problem is getting following Error

Comment: If you create an ODBC connection on each local PC, then open up firewalls on every local PC, to allow the server to access the ODBC connection, then it might be possible, but it's not secure and probably not the correct answer to your real problem.

Comment: @Neil  i want to  using a web service on every local clients! and send request to their web service and get results  from that

Comment: That's kind of the opposite of your original question.   Each local PC is actually a web server, and there is a central web client that connects with each server.  That's a much easier problem to solve.

Comment: Can you check if the user 1 can connect to their own database locally ?

Comment: @HimaanSingh i think you didn't understand the question Himaan

Comment: @Neil you said: "The web browser doesn't (normally) have access to local files, and the web server doesn't have direct access to any files on the local drive (normally)" but i think its not true abut Data-Base!!! because its all depended on the connection string and we can set every think needed to access to users local Db in connection string. its just like when you run your website on IIS ...browser have an access to the database on your system or or anywhere else  which you set in connection string

Comment: @Neil and you said: "That's kind of the opposite of your original question. Each local PC is actually a web server, and there is a central web client that connects with each server. That's a much easier problem to solve" yess...your right but is was just a solution to bypassing the problem

Comment: "its not true abut Data-Base!"  It's true about any file.  Even on a local PC, you might not have access to certain files.   If I give you a connection string pointing to my PC, you won't be able to access it unless I open up the firewalls and give you access.   Unfortunately, opening up like this also gives hackers easier access too.

Comment: If you REALLY want to do this (and I recommend you don't), then this page might help: https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/5229/How-to-allow-ODBC-to-connect-to-SQL-via-and-external-IP.html